# how to put each line of a big string into an array line by line the seperate each line in to names and stream parts?

Tags: php, arrays

i have a big string that has many lines of data as shown below(stream name and stream url). I want to put each line into any array then separate each array value to stream name and stream url then construct corresponding hyperlink for each stream line. could any one show me how this can be done?

Edit:
i put each line in to array but i couldnt split each line in to two parts1! my names array is empty! could any one tell me what is wrong ?

```
$stream_array = explode( "\n", $file_contents );

$names = array();
foreach( $stream_array as $stream ){
  $split = explode( $stream, " " );
  array_push( $names, $split[ 0 ] );

};

print_r($stream_array);
print_r($names);
```

i want to put stream names  in to names array and stream urls into foo array after i put each line of $file_contents into an array .

```
  for($i = 0; $i < count($foo[1]); $i++){

?>

<a href="./doit.php?ID=<?php  echo $foo[1][$i] ; ?>&title= <?php echo $names[0][$i] ;?>"><?php echo $i.") "; echo $names[0][$i] ;?> </a> <br />

<?


}//end of for
```

example of big string that holds list of stream($file_contents):

```
name1 http://somesite.net/all/name1tv.m3u8
name2 http://somesite.net/all/name2tv.m3u8
name3 http://somesite.net/all/name3tv.m3u8
```

Comment: Have you checked out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php?

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy and there are PHP syntax that does most of it for you like so :-

```
// Get a file into an array. 
// Each line will be added as a new occurance of the $lines array
$lines = file('filename.ext');

foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    list($name, $url) = explode(' ', $line);

    echo $name . PHP_EOL; 
    echo $url . PHP_EOL;  

    // of course you will probably want to do something different here 
    // this just shows you whats going on.
}
```

The result would be :

```
name1
http://somesite.net/all/name1tv.m3u8
name2
http://somesite.net/all/name2tv.m3u8
name3 
http://somesite.net/all/name3tv.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it :-)

```
$stream_array = explode( "\n", $file_contents );

    $names = array();
    foreach( $stream_array as $stream ){
      //$split = explode( $stream, " " );
     $split = preg_split('/\s+/', $stream);
     array_push( $names, $split[ 0 ] );

    };

    print_r($stream_array);
    print_r($names);
```

Comment: Loading the regex engine is an unnecessary overhead to solve this requirement